# Do consumer routers implement safeguards against login brute force attacks?

Tags: security, router, brute-force

I'm not talking about trying to crack the encryption key, but if malware got onto your computer, and attempted to brute force your router's login password. I know that the majority of people are using admin/password, but for those that aren't, do router's limit the number of login attempts? I only have one router to test, and it doesn't appear to restrict it. I was just wondering if anyone with more expertise with networking knew if there were security features to prevent this.

The only reason I could think of for doing this would be to keep persistent access in case of the malware being removed, once you have the credentials you can upload a malicious firmware, the router could launch attacks. Since the malware would already be  on a computer behind the router, I couldn't think of another reason to infect it, except for maybe a botnet. I've heard of malicious firmware being used for stuff, but I doubt that much of the stuff littered across the internet would do something like this.

Comment: In my experience, many consumer-grade routers do not protect against this.

Comment: Not on my Netcomm - its unlimited and there isn't even a time delay. I think your thinking of enterprise grade routers from Cisco.

Comment: Agree with Jeremy on this. Maybe you should rather look into Enterprise Solutions

Comment: As per Randolph comments, some can - Cisco implement something called  AOIP (anything over IP) (although I don't think AOIP is specific to Cisco). As the name implies, it means anything from any IP address is monitored/looked at etc (depending on the settings). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some searching with Google and everything I find (along with the comments on this question) indicates that consumer routers do not implement any preventive measures against login brute force attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Even the most basic consumer routers have the ability to only accept connections from specified MAC Addresses. Setting up MAC Address Filtering should at least protect you from wireless hack attempts.